# What does っつの mean?

Tags: usage, slang, て-form, contractions

I recently saw 冗談だっつの. What does it っつの mean, or how does it modify the meaning of a sentence?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

っつ (sometimes つう) is a slang version of という (or an alternate version like といった, depending on the context). It's extremely informal.

> 冗談【じょうだん】だ**っつ**の。 (＝冗談だ【じょうだん】**といった**の。) I said I was joking. [Idiomatically: Chill out, I was just kidding.]
>
> 彼【かれ】はやめたい**っつって**んだから、やめさせてやりゃいいじゃん。 (＝彼【かれ】はやめたい**といっている**んだから、やめさせてやればいいじゃない。) He's saying he wants to quit, so why not let him?
>
> まぁ、なん**つう**かさ、ちょっとまずいっすね。 (＝まぁ、なん**という**かさ、ちょっとまずいですね。) Well, it's…what should I say…kind of a bad situation.

Comment: I always thought っつって came about by (jokingly) pronouncing the っ in って and inserting new っ along the way: だって → だつて → だっつって. At least that's how I picked it up. :-3 Any evidence for or against that theory?

Comment: @deceze: って and っつって mean different things, and therefore it is natural to consider that って did _not_ arise by pronouncing the little っ in って (unless further evidence for the theory exists).  っつって is a very informal contraction of って言って (which itself is a little informal form of と言って).

Comment: While we're on this subject, it's worth pointing out that the entire いる part of 言っている gets dropped sometimes: なにいってんだ？＝なにをいっているんだ？. This is why っつってん expands to といっているん, as Tsuyoshi mentioned.

Comment: I don't see  this mentioned here, and unfortunately I'm not sure how to write it, but is this convo related to "なんっつて"?-just kidding!?

Comment: @yadokari: I imagine なんつって comes from なんかいって, since it's often used to mark speech without an exact wording. (In English, the best parallel is the slang expression, "He was like, '[statement]'.") The alternate use of なんつって to mean "Just kidding!" might be a masculine version of the somewhat feminine なんていっちゃって, which is shortened to なんちゃって.

Comment: sounds about right