# What is the usage of 「つー」, what does it mean and what other ways are there to express the same thing ?

Tags: colloquial-language, て-form, contractions

I've seen this many times in mangas, here's one example:

> アンタなんかが手にしていいお金じゃない**っつーの**！！！

Context: A girl catches a thief that stole today's takings at the shop she's working at.

Thank you! 手伝ってくれてありがとう。

Comment: Possibly related: [What does っつの mean?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/what-does-mean)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a shortening of って言うの!　or って言っているの! and shows some irritation on the part of the speaker. "What I'm telling you is . . .!" There's some good explanations here:   http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1847367.html

Comment: Interesting link, it was once a dialect and is now used nation wide. However I didn't understand well the last part of the first answer "「・・・っつーの」を日常的に用いている地方もありますので，そのような言い方は大変失礼にあたります。" Does it mean that 「。。。っつーの」 is extremely impolite or rude ? It looks colloquial but certainly not that rude, right ?

Comment: Hmmm . . . That last is a little unclear to me, too, but what I *think* it's saying is this: Since っつーの is used routinely in some regions, it strikes him/her as over the top for the other commenters to say that it's rough language.