# Japanese verb to say

Tags: colloquial-language

I was wondering about something that occurs in Japanese I've seen quite often but have yet to find an explanation. I know the Japanese verb to say is 言う, and I know that sometimes you can simply end a sentence with って to indicate implicitly that 言う follows. But I've also seen the following:

[sentence]-っつの such as in the following 大丈夫っつの translated to mean: I said I'm fine.

My question is where does this っつ come from? I'm guessing the の is as in 何をしているの, but the っつ puzzles me. I'm guessing that it's some sort of colloquial speech style such as saying わかんない vs 分からない, and if that's the case, the only verb I can think of is 伝える.

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Writing this as a comment since I am not entirely sure, but in general (I think) つ（う？） instead of 言う is a feature of Edo-ben, still existing in parts of Tokyo and Chiba. I hear people from the Tokyo Shitamachi using it quite often.

Comment: I believe it's the same one as this:  [What does っつの mean?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1252/78)