# what does すんなっつう mean?

Tags: grammar, words, conjugations

hi i was looking for the meaning of the word/words and i'm not sure i got the right meaning the sentence containing the word is

あんなのと一緒にすんなっつうの

Answer (score 3):

すんな is a contraction of するな ("do not").

- [Why is the て-form being used before ん？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/5010)

っつの (っつうの) is like "I say", "I said", "Hey", "Come on", etc.

- [What does っつの mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1252/5010)

あんなの is "something/someone like that" with a derogatory nuance.

> あんなのと一緒にすんなっつうの。
>
> (literally) Do not make [me/it] the same as that!
> Don't lump me in with that bastard!
> Come on, I'm not like that guy!
> Hey, don't think this one is the same as that!